# How to load a GLTF 3D object from a public cloud server in a Vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, npm, 3d, gltf

I have a 3D object in GLTF format hosted on a public cloud server (example: https://files.catbox.moe/sgdtnt.gltf). I want to display this object in my Vue.js application using a package such as vue-3d-model or three. However, all the packages I've found so far only support loading 3D objects from local files.

What is the best way to load a GLTF 3D object from a public cloud server in a Vue.js application? Should I use a specific package or approach to achieve this? Any example code or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you wish to do with the three.js library. You have to define a path during the initialization of the **GLTFLoader** class and then indicate the file you want to display.

Code:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath( 'https://files.catbox.moe/' );
loader.load(
  'sgdtnt.gltf',
  function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene)
  },
  (xhr) => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded')
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
)
```

Working example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/tymoteuszlao/pen/YzJWwBO